# Expandable list-view android, set custom drawables

Tags: android, expandablelistview

ok, i just have a simple question here.
how can i change the group arrow on expandable listview with another drawables?
y know, i'm gonna use + and - for my expandable group list...

Thanks

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Please check [this link](http://android-adda.blogspot.com/2011/06/custom-expandable-listview.html) more helpful to you

---

**OR**

---

```
<ExpandableListView
    android:id="@+id/android:list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:groupIndicator="@drawable/group_indicator" >
```

group_indicator.xml

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_empty="true" android:drawable="@drawable/arrowright"></item>
    <item android:state_expanded="true" android:drawable="@drawable/arrowdown"></item>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/arrowright"></item>
</selector>
```

Comment: "android:groupindicator" should be "android:groupIndicator"